# Are questions about issues with the Ubuntu keyserver on-topic for off-topic distros?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I saw [a question](https://askubuntu.com/q/215784/54298) asking for help related to the [Ubuntu keyserver](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com), but on a computer using Mint.

Although this server is monitored and run by Ubuntu(I think even Canonical), like Ubuntu One, I feel as if a quick cursory glance would close the question.

So, should we allow said questions since they are related to the Ubuntu keyserver, or do we disallow them due to the distro in use by the OP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the question we need to answer is "Is the asker's distro relevant?"  If it isn't, then edit it out of the question to stop hair-trigger closevoters.  If someone can provide evidence that the issue isn't with the keyserver but rather the distro, then it should be migrated.

For instance, in the question you linked it turns out that http://keyserver.ubuntu.com has decided to be an obnoxious sibling and block all communication with Mint, then the distro is relevant.  However, if it turns out that the server's down or I'm typing the command wrong for a non-distro-specific reason, then the distro isn't relevant.

Comment: That's a good point. But, who gets to  decide whether it's relevant? A committee? 5 people? The moderators? Atwood? Mark Shuttleworth? The OP?

Comment: I've added several examples.  Do they make sense?

Comment: I do disagree with the part about the command. The command could be wrong due to a distro-dependent difference.

Comment: In that case, it'd be off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

FAQ says

**We welcome questions about:**

- Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
- Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
- Development on Ubuntu.
- Services provided by Ubuntu

Key server is a service offered by Ubuntu, So it is on topic. but personally I liketocount it as off-topic, because *Services provided by Ubuntu* is too vague

Comment: Just for clarification , I am not Oli

Comment: You lack the diamond.